# Cargar archivos a una carpeta en red con PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Hola compañeros de la comunidad, el dia de hoy me vi con la necesidad de tener que migrar mi documentacion a otro espacio de almacenamiento, pero tengo un sistema que tiene por defecto este servicio para almacenar fotos o archivos, no lo puedo mover por que seria instalar una version de php diferente a la que tiene mi otro servidor y otras aplicaciones ya funcionan con esta version tal y como estan

Para aquellos que se preguntan que sistema operativo uso es windows 10 enterprise y el servidor que planeo usar es window server.

El servidor donde despliego el sistema es en Apache con Xampp

Como podria poner la documentacion en una carpeta de red?

el codigo es el siguiente

HTML

```
<div class="mt-3 my-3 container">
<form class="form-inline">
    <h1>Formato de prueba para carga dentro de otros servidores</h1>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="archvi_pru">
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="subir_archivo_carpeta()" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Confirm identity</button>
</form>
</div>
```

el script por donde mando la instruccion es este

```
function subir_archivo_carpeta() {
    var miArchvio = $("#archvi_pru").prop('files')[0];
    var formData_example = new FormData($(".form-inline")[0]);
    formData_example.append('archvi_pru', miArchvio);
    var ext = $('#archvi_pru').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['zip','pdf','jpg','txt']) == -1) {
        toastr.error('Extencion invalida, solo se pueden aceptar imagenes con extencion .jpg,.pdf,.zip, o .txt', 'Notificacion', {
            "progressBar": true
        });
    }
    else{
       
        //toastr.info(respuesta,'Notificacion')
        $.ajax({
            url: "./php/valida_carga_fotos.php",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData_example,
        }).done(function (respuesta) {
            toastr.success(respuesta, 'Notificación:', {
                "progressBar": true
            })
            // Revisa_info_det_us(id_empleado)
        })
       
    }
}
```

Y el php que se encarga de ejecutar la accion es el siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['archvi_pru'])) {
    include_once 'sesion.php';
    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archvi_pru']['name'];
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archvi_pru']['type'];
    $nombre_temp_archivo = $_FILES['archvi_pru']['tmp_name'];
    $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archvi_pru']['size'];
    $fecha_hoy = date_create(date('Y')."/".date('m')."/".date('d')); 
    $formato = date_format($fecha_hoy,"Y_m_d");
    $ext_archivo = substr($nombre_archivo, strrpos($nombre_archivo, '.'));
    $nombre_archivo_emp = "VAMOS".$ext_archivo;

    $Carpeta = "\\\\105.15.24.45\andres";
    $Archivo_a_remplazar = "\\\\105.15.24.45/andres/$nombre_archivo_emp";
    $nombre_archivo_emp_anterior = "PRUEBA_".$formato.$ext_archivo;
    if (file_exists($Carpeta.$nombre_archivo_emp)) {
        if(rename($Carpeta.$nombre_archivo_emp, $Carpeta.$nombre_archivo_emp_anterior)){
            
            echo " <br> Se pudo cambiar tambien el nombre de la imagen anterior para que quede guardada en el historial.";
         }
         else {
             echo "No se pudo remplazar el nombre de la imagen anterior";
         }
      

    }
    else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($Carpeta, $Carpeta.$nombre_archivo_emp)) {
            echo "El usuario se ha cargado exitosamente.";
        } else {
            echo "El usaurio se registro exitosamente, pero no se ha podido cargar la foto.";
        }
        echo "<br> Se valida que no existe en la carpeta de fotos una foto igual.";
        
    }



}
```

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: correcto creo que ya hice una pregunta mas sencilla

Comment: ¿En una carpeta de red? ¿Es Windows? Lo común es que el usuario con el que se ejecuta el script de php tenga permisos sobre el recurso; tendrías que detallar sobre el sistema operativo, la configuración del servidor web (IIS, Apache, ngix, etc) y de php. ¿Revisaste el log de php?. Antes de probar la carga, primero prueba la lectura simple y después la escritura de un archivo en dicha carpeta de red.

Comment: que servidor usas? como accedes a esa carpeta compartida?

Comment: uso windows 10 enterprise pero despues planeo usar windos server, el servidor que uso en apache con xamppy no  he probado por el momento solo de lectura de la carpeta como podria probarlo?